# Create a query string in a URL (for a link <a>)

Tags: javascript, dom, urlsearchparams

I am trying to create a query string in a URL for a link. I can't find what is the problem, I tried a lot of thing but I always get an "undefined" for "urlCameras". thanks for your help !

```js
const cameras = [{
  _id: "Camera 1"
}];
const linkProduct = document.getElementById("linkProduct");

let url = 'file:///D:/openclassrooms/projet5/orinoco/product.html';
let urlObj = new URL(url);
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let idCameras = cameras[0]._id;
let urlCameras = params.append("?id=", "idCameras");
linkProduct.href = urlCameras;
```

```html
<a id="linkProduct">Click</a>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - please modify if needed to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things

1. `.append("?id=", "idCameras");` should be `.append("id",idCameras)` because

- `?` and `=` - searchParams handles that for you
- don't quote the parameter variable

2. You have too many vars - the URL has its own searchParams you can use

```js
const cameras = [{
  _id: "Camera1"
}];
const linkProduct = document.getElementById("linkProduct");

let url = 'file:///D:/openclassrooms/projet5/orinoco/product.html';
let urlObj = new URL(url);
let idCameras = cameras[0]._id;
urlObj.searchParams.append("id", idCameras);
linkProduct.href = urlObj;
```

```html
<a id="linkProduct">Click</a>
```

Comment: I took off the "?" it was just a try like I had no idea anymore of what to try ;) Thank you very much for your help, it's working !